# How to identify extra virgin olive oil with desired taste profile?

Tags: flavor, olive-oil

While many extra virgin olive oil bottles state “floral” or “fruity”, these seem like generic terms applied to most oils. Similarly, even those that omit the “peppery finish” description, have a pepperiness to my tongue.

However, I once tried my housemate’s dad’s olive oil grown in Portugal and it was *actually floral and fruity.* It also had no pepperiness whatsoever; It tasted like a well-watered Mediterranean meadow, a bouquet of freshly picked wildflowers, and dense stone fruits just harvested.

I was shocked and enamored. And I have never tasted an olive oil like that again. I have sought out Portuguese oils and oils that exclude any mention of “peppery,” but I have yet to taste again an oil like that truly floral and fruity one from so long ago :)

*Here are two sub-points to my question about accurately identifing oils with specific flavor profiles:*

- *Is there any consensus or regulation on the terms used to describe olive oil, or is this entirely at the manufacturer or retailer’s discretion?*
- *Are there particular manufacturers, retailers, places-of-origin, or 3rd-party tasting organizations that use precise and reliable descriptions to help identify an olive oil with the flavor profile that is being sought?*

Comment: Olive oils come from numerous places around the world, and are made with a variety olives. They are also made in different styles and qualities.  The flavor profiles vary widely.  Are you asking for a specific recommendation?  If so, perhaps altering your question to request a producer, region, or olive variety might help.

Comment: I don't see a question here. It's a yes or no answer, and will vary highly according to individual taste, what is peppery to one person may not be to another.

Comment: Hi milo, just as GdD said - this is a subjective question, and as such, not suited for the site. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for types of question we can't take, it is valid across pretty much all sites across the network too.

Comment: I’ve seen specialty olive oil shops before… they have bulk oil dispensers and will fill (or refill) bottles… and they’ll usually offer samples so you can find one with the characteristics you’re looking for.  They’re usually in bigger cities, but I know of one out in the mountains near Harrisonburg, VA.

Comment: @rumtscho : if the question is ‘how to find such an ingredient’, I think it’s answerable.  See my earlier comment

Comment: @Joe this aspect was completely missing from the question when it was closed, I see that it was now edited in. With this new aspect, I agree that it ould be brought into an answerable form. The current edit makes it a shopping recommendation question, which is also closable. But if it is made more general, without asking for the name of a product or manufacturer, then it could be reopened, and your comment reposted as an answer.

Comment: I think it's reopenable. We can definitely recommend varietals of olive oil that are "high fruit, low pepper", based on authoritative resources.

Comment: @FuzzyChef the criterion is not whether there are authorative sources, but whether it would be a recommendation question - "these brands are the right ones to buy, here is the list" (that would be closable) - or a more generic question whose answer is not a list of brands, but a description of how to go about finding sources of olive oil outside of a supermarket carrying a few big brands, or how to find information on the taste of potential products.

Comment: @milo thanks for editing, the new version looks not only answerable, but also quite interesting! Reopened and upvoted.

Comment: @rumtscho I want to edit my question in italics at the bottom to: “How does one accurately identify oils with specific flavor profiles? (Bonus for addressing either sub-question.)” Its a bit redundant to the title, but will make it easier to accept an answer, as right now I am asking people to answer to questions, which I think rarely happens. Would you recommend this?

Answer (score 4):

I'll speak to the first bullet. There is absolutely consensus and criteria for judging the quality and characteristics of olive oil. There is, for example, a [World Olive Oil competition](https://nyiooc.org/), which makes use of a set of criteria.

The [International Olive Oil Council](https://www.internationaloliveoil.org/) governs 95% of world wide olive oil production.  T[heir standards](https://www.internationaloliveoil.org/what-we-do/chemistry-standardisation-unit/standards-and-methods/) (many documents) may give you insight into what you are looking for. They have guidelines for tasting panels, for example, that specify the criteria that you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an identifier, which raises the probability that the oil will be to your liking. It is the variety/cultivar of the olives used for the making of the oil. There are multiple sites describing the cultivars ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_olive_cultivars), [OliveOilTimes](https://www.oliveoiltimes.com/basics/how-many-olive-varieties-are-there/84373)), but my suggestion is to first ask your housemate, what cultivar does his dad use and try to buy/taste some other oils of that cultivar. I am personally quite partial to Picual, but I like grassy flavors.

This approach has one side-effect (possibly downside): It will steer you towards more expensive olive oils which actually declare their content (and which will probably describe their taste at least a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Olive oil is a lot like wine, in that you can predict some characteristics based on the olive variety and/or where it’s grown.  But how it’s pressed (cold vs hot, if solvents are used) and how it’s stored (temperature, length of time) can also affect the flavor.

Most ‘olive oil’ sold in the United States is a blend (more like ‘apple juice’ than wines from a single variety of olive.  You can occasionally find Kalamata olive oil in stores, but most stores usually don’t bother.  They might have an ‘American’, ‘Italian’, ‘Spanish’, ‘Turkish’, or blends.  (And beware of country names—- they often list where it was packaged and you have to look at the fine print for where it was grown.

There exist ‘olive oil stores’ that will have a larger variety, sorted more like wine varieties and will typically offer samples so you can taste for yourself which variety you prefer (and are willing to spend the money on; these places aren’t necessarily inexpensive, but some will fill/refill bottles from large dispensers so they may be able to keep costs down)